# Firefox innerHTML Bug?

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have a simple piece of HTML

```
<p id="skills">Skills</p>
```

in Firefox 3.6.3 when I call (with JQuery):

```
$("#skills")[0].innerHTML = "some new text"
```

Firefox renders it as

```
<p id="skills"><a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">some new text</a></p>
```

Where in the world is that link coming from??

(note the same thing happens by calling `$("#skills").html("some new text")` with JQuery)

Comment: Man, the same thing has been happening to me too! It's driving me nuts.

Comment: @nickf - Try disabling all the web developer addons you're probably running?  This *has* to be an extension issue...

Comment: It wasn't a firebug or plugin issue, see below for a demo page showing what I'm experiencing

Comment: For the record, that's not really a link, it's an XML namespace. http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my sample code excluded the portion which is the actual problem, here is a working sample page to show the issue. When you change the html of any element within a link, it wraps all text with 
`<a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">THE TEXT</a>`

In my demo when you click the "test" link, it will replace the html within skills with:

```
<a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">some new text</a>
```

This may not be a "bug", but it seems firefox is the only browser that does it.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function test() {
        $("#skills")[0].innerHTML = "some new text"
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" onclick="test()">test</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">
      <p id="skills">Skills</p>
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're correct in that Firefox is doing something unexpected here, *but*, that's not valid HTML, so it's not guaranteed to behave in any certain way.  You're not allowed to have a block element inside an anchor, if you change that `<p>` to a `<span>` which *is* valid then it works.  You can check your sample HTML for validity here: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: I just got bit by this while trying to debug a WMD preview issue in Firefox.  The preview div was inside a b tag set to display:block.  Firefox apparently ignores the CSS attributes and says "NO, you can't do that!"  I call that a bug, but I know I'd be fighting a losing battle if I tried to submit it.

Answer (score 7):

It's not a bug in Firefox, you're getting an extra `<a></a>` in there in the first place...I'd disable all your plugins and try again, something specific on your install is interfering here.

I assume you're viewing this with Firebug, does the exact example you gave above (with nothing else in the page) do the same thing?  You can try a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Wcjk9/

### **Update:**

Your example does indeed show some weird behavior in Firefox, *however* it's "allowed" to do this.  Since you have invalid HTML, the browser can and indeed is giving some funky behavior here.  The parser/scripting engine in the browser is free to *assume* you have valid HTML, like unique IDs for example.  If you have invalid HTML, well...it can't be held responsible.  I have to include [this quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640/great-programming-quotes/59001#59001):

> On two occasions I have been asked, 'Pray, Mr. Babbage, if you put into the machine wrong figures, will the right answers come out?' I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question.

Ignoring the errors that jsbin adds, [you can see the problem here](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsbin.com%2Fowuxi%2F4&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) (the first validation error).  You are not allowed to have a block element inside an anchor.  You *can* have an inline element, if you replace the `<p>` in your example with a `<span>` you'll have valid HTML...and this weird behavior goes away :)

Comment: Yeah I'd have to agree with you on this.  Something is hijacking the innerHTML request.  Your demo worked fine from here.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there's an addon on your side or your HTML is somehow malformed. Try disabling your addons and running your HTML through a validator (http://validator.w3.org).

Also, if all you intend to change is the text and aren't adding any HTML I would recommend using the [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function instead of the html function (Though I doubt this will fix your issue, just saying it's the right tool for the job)

Comment: There is virtually no difference between text and html in this case except that the html function will replace text more efficiently...

Comment: Yes, but I highly suspect that this isn't the finished objective. As I said I don't think that will fix his problem (The first paragraph might though), I'm just recommending as a sidenote using the text function if you don't plan to set any actual HTML. I think as a general rule the extra security of it's well and truly worth the small overhead, plus right tool for the job etc.