# why innerHTML does not return true when compared with same string value?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I have two tables on my html page with exact same data but there may be few difference which need to be highlighted.
I and using the below Javascript but seems innerHTML does not work as expected-

```
function CompareTables()
{
var table1 = document.getElementById("table1")
var table2 = document.getElementById("table2")



for(var i=1; i < table1.rows.length; i++)
{
    for(var j=1; j < table2.rows.length; j++){
        var tab1Val = table1.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML;
        var tab2Val = table2.rows[j].cells[0].innerHTML;
        alert(tab1Val.toUpperCase()+"----"+tab2Val.toUpperCase());

        var changes =RowExists(table2,tab1Val);

        if(!changes[0])
        {
        table1.rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
        instHasChange = true;
        }
}
 function RowExists(table,columnValue)
{
 var hasColumnOrChange = new Array(2);
 hasColumnOrChange[0] = false;
  for(var i=1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
 {

 if(table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML == columnValue) /*** why these two does not match**/
 {
   hasColumnOrChange[0] = true;
  }
 return hasColumnOrChange;
}
}
```

Please suggest what wrong here.
(`table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML == columnValue`) never returns true even if all values same.

Comment: why dont you do a console.log of both values and see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and use [Jquery's method .text](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Depending on the browser(Firefox and Chrome's) innerHTML does not work

JQuery takes care of that issue for you.

Comment: finally i implemented the code in jquery. thanks all for help & suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

most browsers have bugs with `innerHTML` and it is not a recommended property to use. different browsers will do different things, usually messing with whitespace, adding/removing quotes, and/or changing the order of attributes.

long story short, never rely on `innerHTML`.

In it's place, I would recommend using some of the DOM traversal functions, such as [.firstChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.firstChild) and [.nodeValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.nodeValue). Notice that these are sensitive of white space, and will have to be tweaked if you have anything else in your TD than just text.

http://jsfiddle.net/tdN5L/

```
if (table.rows[i].cells[0].firstChild.nodeValue === columnValue)
```

Another option, as pointed out by Micah's solution, is using a library such as jQuery, which will let you ignore most of these browser issues and DOM manipulation pain. I would not recommend bringing in the overhead of jQuery just for this issue, though.

related:

[Firefox innerHTML Bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940826/firefox-innerhtml-bug)

[innerHTML bug IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896208/innerhtml-bug-ie8)

[innerHTML removes attribute quotes in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231770/innerhtml-removes-attribute-quotes-in-internet-explorer?rq=1)