# innerHTML strings aren't equal to the same string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom

Here's my problem. The code below is a simplified version to point out the weird error.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    window.onload = function test()
    {
    body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'div';
                body.appendChild(div);
                document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = "text";
                if(document.getElementById('div').childNodes[0] == "text")
                    {
                        alert('true');
                    }else {
                        alert('false');
                    }
                }
</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Why is it false!? Its virtually the SAME EXACT string. Is it the 
`.innerHTML` part? Any answer relevant to this issue would help. It's late at night and I'm angry and confused.

Comment: There could be some spaces issue!

Comment: childNodes[0].textContent?

Comment: try childNodes[0].data or value

Comment: Exact duplicate of **[why innerHTML does not return true when compared with same string value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584542/why-innerhtml-does-not-return-true-when-compared-with-same-string-value)**

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the `nodeValue` of your child node instead since `childNodes` return an object:

```
if (document.getElementById('div').childNodes[0].nodeValue == "text")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, just wondering though, what exactly causes the problem above?

Comment: `childNodes` return an object. You cannot compare object with a string literal.